# using git post-receive for overwriting files in multiple directories

Tags: git, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, webserver, git-post-receive

I'm using git to deploy changes to the files on my server, but the files live in two directories (/var/www and /user/myfiles) but I want to just use one repo to push the changes. So I've set up a repo (/user/gitrepo) and I think, after looking around for solutions, the best approach is to use post-receive to overwrite the files in the other directories, but I don't know how to use the hook post-receive to do what I want (I'm a git noob). Can any one help?

To be clear I have files in user/gitrepo/www/file1 and user/gitrepo/myfiles/file2

I want to push changes to the repo and have var/www/file1 and user/myfiles/file2 be updated.

Thanks!

(also if you have something you think should work better and also uses git, could you give me a detailed how-to?).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for an introduction to git hooks.

Try:

- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks
- http://ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook/
- http://google.com/?q=git+post-receive+hook+example

Answer (score 0):

If your remote server is linux (which it likely is) you can use any terminal commands within your remote server.

Say for example you wish to delete a file you can use the command
`rm file2`

You can chain as many commands in the hook as you like.
To copy the contents of one folder to another you could use: `cp Folder1/* Folder2/`